# Spark-Hive-Sqoop: Saving data in hive table using Spark showing junk char with Sqoop export

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to load data from  hive table(hivetable1) then making some modification to it using spark and again saving in another table(hivetable2) in hive.
when I do select * from hivetable2, it shows me proper data but when I try to see the same file in hdfs it shows all junk char as below.
When I try to export same data in postgres using Sqoop it appends the entire data in postgres table's single column.

Spark script:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate() 

df = spark.sql("select * from hivetable1")

df.write.format("hive").mode('overwrite').option("delimiter", "\t").saveAsTable("hivetable2")
```

Hdfs file data:

hadoop fs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/tb.db/hivetable2/part-0000

[image]

lnullunknownnullnullnull\N\N\N\Nnullnullnullnullnull0.00.0nullnull\Nnull\Nnullnullnullnullnull\Nnullnull\Nnullnullnull\Nnullnullnull\Nnullnull

Sqoop Export:

```
 sqoop export --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?stringtype=unspecified -m 1 --table test --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/tb.db/hivetable2 \
 --username test --password test --input-fields-terminated-by '\t'
```

Comment: hadoop fs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/tb.db/part-m this I am using to view content, When I read other files in hdfs, I am able to see them

Comment: I am actually loading data in hive table using sqoop from postgres in text format and I am able to view those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to create a hive table seperately and append the data into the table.
Secondly once done you can sqoop back to database.

df.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("database_name.table", overwrite=True)